# How to fix error 1452 and relate tables properly

Tags: mysql

I am creating an Online exam system. In the database I can't seem to relate my tables properly and causing to experience error. When I submit the data to tbl_choices table I get the error 1452. Any idea what to do?

I have tried executing it in sql and in relation view but does not seem to work. I have also watched several videos about creating table with foreign key and altering the table.

[tbl_qtopic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xb3sg.png)

[tbl_question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3WmL.png)

[tbl_choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1aIS.png)

**tbl_qtopic:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_qtopic` (
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `topic_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `date_created` date NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

**tbl_question:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_question` (
  `ques_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ques` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `tbl_question`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_question` FOREIGN KEY (`topic_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_qtopic` (`topic_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;
```

**tbl_choice:**

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_choices` (
  `ch_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ques_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ques` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `ch_des1` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `ch_des2` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `ch_des3` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `ch_des4` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `ans` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

ALTER TABLE `tbl_choices`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_choices` FOREIGN KEY (`ques_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_question` (`ques_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Here is the error message.

```
Error Number: 1452

Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`examsystem`.`tbl_choices`, CONSTRAINT `fk_choices` FOREIGN KEY (`ques_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_question` (`ques_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE)

INSERT INTO `tbl_choices` (`ques`, `ch_des1`, `ch_des2`, `ch_des3`, `ch_des4`, `ans`) VALUES ('What does \'SQL\' stands for?', 'Super Query Language', 'Standard Query Language', 'Structured Query Language', 'Structured Question Language', '3')
```

Comment: You need to specify `ques_id` in insert

Comment: Can you please explain how? I've been stuck in this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foreign key basically says, that there needs to be an entry in the referenced table (the parent table) for each entry in the table that has the foreign key (the child table). It prevents that there are children without parents, so to say.

This means, that you have to insert in the proper order, in your case first there needs to be an entry in `tbl_qtopic` that can be referenced in `tbl_question`. Then you `insert` in `tbl_question` so that this entry can be referenced in `tbl_choices`.

For this to be easily done, you should have a primary key that is also an auto_increment column. Also note, you should **always** have a primary key in your table.

Your tables should look like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_qtopic` (
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `topic_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

CREATE TABLE `tbl_question` (
  `ques_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `topic_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `ques` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET latin1 NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_question` FOREIGN KEY (`topic_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_qtopic` (`topic_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Then you simply do your inserts in a transaction. A transaction bundles several statements, so that if one statement fails, all statements in the transaction are undone (rolled back). After each insert you save the `id` that was generated in the auto_increment column and use this value for your next `insert` statement.

Note, this is just MySQL code. You have to look up how you do this in PHP or whatever you use yourself. I'm a database admin, not a programmer :)

```
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO tbl_qtopic (topic_name, description) VALUES ('foo', 'bar');
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID(); /* store this value in a variable */
INSERT INTO tbl_question (topic_id, ques) VALUES (<the value from above select>, 'baz');
COMMIT;
```

You get the idea, I guess. Note, that you don't need the `auto_increment` column in the `insert` statements. The values for those are automatically generated. I left out the table `tbl_choices` in the example intentionally, because it needs a redesign. Don't have several columns for ch_des ("choice description" I guess?). That's bad design. What if a question has 5 choices? What if one only has 3? Do you add a column and have several rows with NULL values in certain columns? Make those columns rows. You don't need to enforce a 1:1 relationship between tables. Read up about database normalization!
The column `ans` is supposed to be the correct answer to the question? It probably shouldn't be in this table, especially when you have your choices to a question as rows, not columns. The design of tables is a huge topic and way too much to be answered in this question. Open another question, if you need help with this.

Finally, some literature for you:

- [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id)
- [database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: A word of advice: A proper Character set should probably be `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`